# Polynomial complexity algorithm of partition problem with sets of equal size

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

Partition problem is well known ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem ).

Let's add an additional condition: sizes of both sets should be equal. Is there a pseudo-polynomial solution to that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Given a list $S$ of positive integers, add $\max(S)\cdot \mathrm{length}(S)$ to each element, and denote the resulting list by $S'$. Run the algorithm for the partition problem on $S'$, and accept if and only if it accepts. This is correct because partitions $S'=S'_1\cup S'_2$ are equivalent to partitions $S=S_1\cup S_2$ where $|S_1|=|S_2|$.

Comment: My kudos for a nice method! I suppose that $\sum(S)$ instead of $\max(S)\cdot \mathrm{length}(S)$ is also satisfies the solution, right?

Comment: Yep. Another reduction would be to send $s\in S$ to $1+s\cdot \mathrm{length}(S)$.

Comment: How does this work? It just offsets each element of _S_ by a constant. Intuitively, only differences between elements should influence the partition, not the absolute values, that is, partitioning of {1, 2, 3, 4} should be isomorphic to partitioning of {101, 102, 103, 104}. What am I missing?